# Request for Tag Creation: Nestorianism, Chalcedonian, Monophysitism, Miaphysitism

Tags: feature-request, tags

I wish to request the creation of the following tags in whichever grammatical case is best: Nestorianism, Chalcedonian, Monophysitism, Miaphysitism.

Edit: On this question: [Is it Proper to State that Chalcedonianism is a Moderate Position In-between Nestorianism and Monophysitism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/is-it-proper-to-state-that-chalcedonianism-is-a-moderate-position-in-between-nes)

Apparently Chalcedonianism isn't a word.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Tags are not created on their own, they are added to questions on an as needed basis. We cannot create tags except by placing them on appropriate questions. In order to add tags, a question must first be asked and then somebody with enough reputation points can add the tag. In fact with just s couple hundred points you will be able to create them yourself. For now please just note in a comment any time you think a new tag is in order for a question.

Comment: There is such a request here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/is-it-proper-to-state-that-chalcedonianism-is-a-moderate-position-in-between-nes

Comment: @AndrewLeach thank you for the link. Yes, would it be possible for someone with tag power to put it on that question?

Comment: Caleb would you please make a Docetism tag on this question: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20012/were-all-the-various-systems-of-gnosticism-docetist

Answer (score 2):

One of those things is not like the other, one of those things just doesn't fit in. Consider the following dumb sentence; I'll see your chalcedonianism and raise you two vaticanisms and a trentism.

I'm pretty sure only doctrines and heresies get -isms not councils.  I'm not sure Chalcedon.* makes a good tag unless it's about the Council of Chalcedon.

Comment: Perhaps Chalcedonian-Christianity?

Comment: After I get tag creation powers I'll probably make a Council of Chalcedon tag separately from "Chalcedonianism"

Comment: That just means "normal Christianity" though, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but given the secular mission of this stack exchange, I would find it appropriate, especially considering that Nestorians and Mono/miaphysites still exist. However my aim was only to use the tag for questions pertaining to the 4th, 5th, and 6th ecumenical councils and the debates between the three differing perspectives on Christology.